# Can't use AudioRecord During call

Tags: android, audio-recording

My app needs to visualize voice when a call occurs, so I registered a `Service` to listen to call states.

So when `onAttachedView` occurs I call my mic record class which extends `Thread` and this is the run method:

```
public void run() {
try {
        mRecordInstance.startRecording();
        float splValue = 0.0f;
        float rmsValue = 0.0f;

        while (this.mIsRunning) {
                // creating these variables here so that
                // the mode change can be handled
                int SIZE = BUFFSIZE;
                short[] tempBuffer = new short[SIZE];
                mRecordInstance.read(tempBuffer, 0, SIZE);

                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++) {
                        rmsValue += tempBuffer[i] * tempBuffer[i];
                }
                rmsValue = rmsValue / SIZE;
                rmsValue = (float) Math.sqrt(rmsValue);
                splValue =  (float) (20 * Math.log10(rmsValue / P0));
                splValue = splValue + mCaliberationValue;
                splValue = (float) round(splValue, 2);

                if (mMaxValue < splValue) {
                        mMaxValue = splValue;
                }

                if (!mShowMaxValue) {
                        Message msg = mHandle.obtainMessage(MY_MSG, splValue);
                        mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
                } else {
                        Message msg = mHandle.obtainMessage(MY_MSG, mMaxValue);
                        mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        msg = mHandle.obtainMessage(MAXOVER_MSG, mMaxValue);
                        mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
                        mShowMaxValue = false;
                }

                writeLog(splValue);
        }
   } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Message msg = mHandle.obtainMessage(ERROR_MSG, 
                                                            e.getLocalizedMessage()+"");
            mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
    }
    if(mRecordInstance != null){
            mRecordInstance.stop();
            mRecordInstance.release();
            mRecordInstance = null;
    }
}
```

This class sends a message via handler to the class that visualize the voice. it works great when off call a circle is drawn by the voice decibel level.

When I am in call I don't receive mic input.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to say, you want to record VOICE_DOWNLINK i.e. Recieved audio during voice call ?
If so, you can specify the source of media as :

```
m_Recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
```